# List of possible overloads for Jersey JAX-RS resources

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I'm using Jersey to implement a JAX-RS resource. I've seen lots of different examples on Stack Overflow, various blogs and the [Jersey User Guide](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/index.html).

I would like to know what the different overloads can be for a given resource handler. Is there a single source where these are documented?

For example, the following handles an HTTP POST request. The request body is captured as a `MultivaluedMap`.

```
@POST
public Response httpPostRequest(MultivaluedMap<String, String> body)
{
    ...
}
```

Alternatively, the following overload captures the body as a single `String`.

```
@POST
public Response httpPostRequest(String body)
{
    ...
}
```

There are other overloads too. How many are there and where are they documented?

Answer (score 0):

It is just a normal Java method that has one or more annotations associated with it. The signature of the method has no particular constraints placed on it by Jersey.

Having said that, you will want to make sure that the various annotations (e.g., `@Produces`, `@Consumes`, `@PathParam`, `@QueryParam`) are applied to data types that Jersey knows how to map. For example, Jersey has no problem with mapping `@PathParam` to `String` or `long`. Jersey can also work with Java classes that have JAXB annotations, so your method signature can include a JAXB type combined with `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)` and Jersey will convert the request content from an XML document to the JAXB Java class.

For example:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Path("somepath")
public Foos getFoosByQuery(@PathParam("businessName") String businessName,
        @PathParam("businessUnitName") String businessUnitName, @PathParam("fileType") String fileType,
        @QueryParam("from") String fromString, @QueryParam("to") String toString,
        @DefaultValue("10") @QueryParam("interval") int intervalMinutes,
        @DefaultValue("1000") @QueryParam("limit") int limit,
        @DefaultValue("false") @QueryParam("errors") boolean errors) {
```

Here, we see that we have many parameters (with types `String`, `int` and `boolean`) and a return type that is a JAXB-annotated POJO. Jersey pulls the `@PathParam` values from the path, the `@QueryParam` values from the query string and converts the return value into an XML document and includes it as the content of the response.

I will also note that the name of the method can be anything we want, so the concept of "overloading" is orthogonal to Jersey. The normal Java overloading rules apply.

It should be obvious from this example that you cannot enumerate all of the possible "overloads" that you can use with Jersey.

Perhaps a different question regarding all of the possible type mappings that Jersey can do would be more in line with what you are looking for.

Comment: I don't understand how the signature can have no constraints.